# Systemd timer OnCalendar based on instance name with calculation

Tags: linux, systemd, time

I have a systemd timer that is templated. The instance names are all just integers (`mytimer@1.timer` etc).

Is it possible, in the OnCalendar directive, to have the calendar expression perform basic math on `%i`?

What I would like to do, is basically multiply the value in `%i` by 5, for example, so that I can have one template for the timers and offset their start times by 5 minutes times `%i`, rather than just making separate timer units for each timer.

My thought is it might look something like this:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00:$$(%i * 5):00
```

I know this syntax is illegal, since I tried it in a sandbox timer unit I made, but, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, using a single templated timer?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not aware of any math capabilities, maybe this can satisfy your needs:

You could add `RandomizedDelaySec` to your timer template, which distributes the starting time evenly among the timers.

> ```
>    RandomizedDelaySec=
>       Delay the timer by a randomly selected, evenly distributed
>       amount of time between 0 and the specified time value.
>       Defaults to 0, indicating that no randomized delay shall be
>       applied. Each timer unit will determine this delay randomly
>       before each iteration, and the delay will simply be added on
>       top of the next determined elapsing time, unless modified
>       with FixedRandomDelay=, see below.
>
>       This setting is useful to stretch dispatching of similarly
>       configured timer events over a certain time interval, to
>       prevent them from firing all at the same time, possibly
>       resulting in resource congestion.
> ```

Additionally, `FixedRandomDelay` can be set to `true`, to persist the random delay and re-use it for future runs.

> ```
>    FixedRandomDelay=
>        Takes a boolean argument. When enabled, the randomized offset
>        specified by RandomizedDelaySec= is reused for all firings of
>        the same timer. For a given timer unit, the offset depends on
>        the machine ID, user identifier and timer name, which means
>        that it is stable between restarts of the manager. This
>        effectively creates a fixed offset for an individual timer,
>        reducing the jitter in firings of this timer, while still
>        avoiding firing at the same time as other similarly
>        configured timers.
> ```

Source: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.timer.5.html aka `man systemd.timer`